# can't scrape amazon with beautifulsoup. not a header problem

Tags: python

i would like to **scrape** amazon top 10 bestsellers in baby-products.
i want just the titel text but it seems that i have a problem.
im getting 'None' when I'm trying this code.
after getting "result" i want to iterate it using "content" and print the titles.
thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/baby-products"

r=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print("status: ", r.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
print("url: ", r.url)

result = soup.find("ol", {"id": "zg-ordered-list"})
content = result.findAll("div", {"class": "a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative"})

print(result)
print(content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to scrape the Amazon website in this way. You are using `requests.get` to get the HTTP response body of the url provided. Pay attention to what that response actually is (e.g. by `print(r.content)`). What you can see in your web browser is different than the raw HTTP response, because of client-side rendering technologies used by Amazon (typically JavaScript and others).

I advice you to use Selenium, which sorts of "emulates" the typical browser inside the Python runtime, renders the site like the normal browser would do and allows you to access properties of the same website you see in your web browser.